# What does "Percent Trucks in Design Lane" input represent?

Tags: civil-engineering, pavement

In the AASHTO Pavement ME program version 2.6, for the traffic input "Percent Trucks in Design Lane" is the default value of 95% based on the maximum percent of trucks that can occur in the design lane or the average percent of trucks that ride in the design lane?